# Laravel pass data into mail for different recipents

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3, swiftmailer

I just created a newsletter in Laravel, where people can register with their email-adress and then somebody can send a mail to those who are registered. 
Then I save those registrations in a table, together with the relating id of the sender of the newsletter (in my case its a seller, and buyers register for a newsletter)....

This is the code I use then so send a newsletter:

```
 public function sendNewsletter(Request $request){
        $newsletterText = $request->newsletterText;
        $seller = Auth::user();
        $sellerID = $seller->id;
        $newsletterMailAdresses = Newsletter::where('seller_id', $sellerID)->pluck('mailAdress');

        Mail::bcc($newsletterMailAdresses)->send(new newsletterMail($newsletterText));
        return "<p style='color:green;'>Newsletter erfolgreich versandt</p>";
    }
```

Its called with an AJAX request, but shouldn't change anything...

What I need now is to give the users the possibility to unsubscribe from the newsletter as well, via a link in the mail.

This is the corresponding mail class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class newsletterMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $newsletterText;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($newsletterText)
    {
        $this->newsletterText = $newsletterText;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $subject = "Newsletter ShoppingPortal";
        return $this->view('emails.newsLetter')->subject($subject);
    }
}
```

And that's the mail view:

```
Newsletter vom Shoppingportal: <br/><br/>

<div>
    {!!$newsletterText!!}
</div>


<br/>

To unsubscribe from Newsletter, use this link: localhost/unsubscribe/....
```

And here's the thing missing, I need to create a link to unsubscribe, therefore I would need the sellerID in the view (what would be possible, could just pass it in like the newsletterText, but HOW can I pass in or get the current mail adress the email is sent to? As this mail goes to some recipents, its different in each instance of the view... How can I do this, so how can I get the mail adress in the view?

Comment: Why not use a newsletter service, like mailchimp, and integrate using the API? Most web servers aren't meant to send mass mailers, and it may even be flagged as spam.

Comment: Instead of sending the senderID use the registrationId, with that id you will be able to get the details of the subscriber and the sender as well

Comment: @HalfCrazed as its a small project so far and i don't know how far it will grow this is okay...

Comment: @phobia82 and how could I pass this id in? still the same problem, in the view, I don't know at which recipent its sent...

Answer (score 0):

I got it,

just changed the sending of the mail to this:

```
foreach($newsletterMailAdresses as $mailAdress){
            Mail::to($mailAdress)->send(new NewsletterMail($newsletterText, $mailAdress, $sellerID));
        }
```

Now I have the current mail adress while sending.